# How to develop sbt plugin for Play 2.3?

Tags: playframework, sbt, playframework-2.3

Could anybody help me to get [play-plovr-plugin](https://github.com/benmccann/play-plovr-plugin/blob/sbt-web/src/main/scala/com/benmccann/playplovr/PlayPlovrPlugin.scala) working? It doesn't seem to be triggered. I have the following code in the plugin, but I cannot seem to get the plugin to be triggered from my Play 2.3 project:

```
override def projectSettings: Seq[Setting[_]] =
    inConfig(Assets)(basePlovrSettings) ++
    inConfig(TestAssets)(basePlovrSettings) ++
    Seq(
      plovr in Assets := (plovr in Assets).dependsOn(WebKeys.webModules in Assets).value,
      plovr in TestAssets := (plovr in TestAssets).dependsOn(WebKeys.webModules in TestAssets).value
    )
```

Comment: i'm not sure, but this could be due to play 2.3 uses sbt 0.13.5, which treats plugins differently. did you explicitly activated the plugin? something like: `lazy val root = (project in file(".")).enablePlugins(PlayPlovrPlugin)`

Comment: gilad, thanks for the suggestion. i think it was not clear before, so i just clarified that this is a plugin i am writing and think the problem is in the way i have written the plugin

Comment: What do you mean by not triggered? When I checked out your plugin, it shows in `about`, I can also do `web-assets:plovr` (which doesn't work, but is executed). What is the behaviour you expect?

Comment: @lpiepiora I couldn't get it to be executed. I hadn't tried "web-assets:plovr", but you're right that it executes the plugin. However, I think that task is supposed to hook into my web project such that it's executed automatically somehow when you compile the project or receive a request or something. So it seems like that's the part that's not working correctly. I'm trying to get this to work with Play 2.3. Any ideas there?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all your plugin is activated. You can check it by executing `about`, where all the plugins are listed. Among them yours plugin.

```
[info] Available Plugins: ... com.benmccann.playplovr.PlayPlovrPlugin...
```

That means you can execute it via `web-assets:plovr`.

However as you've mentioned you want it to be executed by the way of the compile. You can say that your task is triggered by the compile.

In your `projectSettings` add

```
plovr in Assets <<= (plovr in Assets).triggeredBy(compile in Compile)
```

e.g.

```
override def projectSettings: Seq[Setting[_]] =
    inConfig(Assets)(basePlovrSettings) ++
    inConfig(TestAssets)(basePlovrSettings) ++
    Seq(
      plovr in Assets := (plovr in Assets).dependsOn(WebKeys.webModules in Assets).value,
      plovr in TestAssets := (plovr in TestAssets).dependsOn(WebKeys.webModules in TestAssets).value,
      plovr in Assets <<= (plovr in Assets).triggeredBy(compile in Compile)
    )
```

Just to sum it up, the

```
  override def requires = SbtWeb

  override def trigger = AllRequirements
```

will activate your plugin (as you can see in `about`) and add its settings, but you must tell it what the settings you want. [You could read interesting article, which should explain it.](http://typesafe.com/blog/preview-of-upcoming-sbt-10-features-read-about-the-new-plugins)

Comment: Thank you so much for the great explanation. That was truly helpful and I learned a lot. I submitted a pull request to the sbt-web project to add some of this explanation to their documentation (https://github.com/sbt/sbt-web/pull/50)